# SQL produces constant erorrs when importing dataframes from Python/Pandas: SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "table" does not exist

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I imported data frames from Python/Pandas to SQL.

They have successfully converted into tables with column data in Postgres.

When working with this imported data in Postgres/SQL I keep getting strange error messages I would not normally encounter with standard SQL tables / data.

```
select * from table;

SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "table" does not exist
  Position: 15
```

This error message comes when trying to read columns, do joins, basically anything you could normally do in SQL. So I attribute it to point to the root of the problem.

Is there some repurposing or reformatting that must be done to SQL database tables after they've been imported from Python/ Jupyter / Pandas?

edit: the table and it's columns definitely do exist within the database. They're just not registering in SQL queries.

Comment: The message means that you are trying to query a table that does not exist in the database.  Without seeing a [mre] it's impossible to say more.

Comment: I understand this is what the message means. This is the basic answer I run into when searching for a solution to the problem. The table definitely exists and so does it's data, it's just not clicking into SQL queries.

Comment: I'll bet either: 1) The table name is something like "TABLE" or "Table" and you need to do what I just did and double quote it to preserve case or 2) You have a `search_path` setting that is 'hiding' the schema the table is in and you need schema qualify the table name e.g. some_schema.table. Then change your search_path so you don't have to do that.

Comment: Suggestion 2 solved the issue. Setting the schema search path worked to enable accessing the tables within the database.